# Inverse of the cumulative gaussian distribution in R

Tags: r, gaussian, normal-distribution

How can I calculate inverse of the cumulative gaussian distribution in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `qnorm`:

```
qnorm(.025)
# [1] -1.959964
qnorm(.5)
# [1] 0
qnorm(.975)
# [1] 1.959964
```