# z() function Signal Detection Theory in R

Tags: r, signals, detection

I am trying to follow chapter 2 on SDT in
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-03499-3_2

It basically says
d'emp = z(HIT) - z(FA)

if you don't know z() let your computer compute it ..

But how? Is there a function in R? It cannot be scale becaus Hit and FA are single values.

Answer (score 1):

In this book, the z-transformation z() is defined as "the inverse cumulative Gaussian function". I think the sentence "If you are not familiar with the z-transformation just treat it as a function you can find on your computer" means for readers to not stop too much time in what does z-transformation means and pay attention to the calculations of d_emp and b_emp as the differences and the average.

However, if you want to know how to compute the inverse cumulative Gaussian (normal) function, you can use `qnorm()` from `stats`library. Be aware that you have to specify the mean and sd of the population, by default the function takes mean = 0 and sd = 1.

To know more:

[Inverse of the cumulative gaussian distribution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035825/inverse-of-the-cumulative-gaussian-distribution-in-r)

https://www.statology.org/dnorm-pnorm-rnorm-qnorm-in-r/

Comment: Many thanks. The figures in table 2.3 can be computed with qnorm()